# How do you find the best set of stack movements that will sort a *known* list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization

Much is known about the problem of sorting unknown lists. But what about the problem of finding the optimal sorting for a **known list** in a stack machine? That is, suppose you have the following stack machine:

```
[4,1,3,2]
[]
[]
```

That is, there is room for 3 stacks, and 1 of them is filled with numbers. Moreover, suppose that your stack machine can execute 2 movements: `move a b` (places the top element of the `a` onto `b`), and `join a b` (puts stack `a` on top of stack `b`). On that case, the optimal sort is:

```
move 0 1
move 0 1
move 0 2
join 1 2
move 0 2
```

Which will execute the following sequence:

```
[4,1,3,2] → [4,1,3] → [4,1] → [4]   → [4]     → []
[]        → [2]     → [2,3] → [2,3] → []      → []
[]        → []      → []    → [1]   → [1,2,3] → [1,2,3,4]
```

How do you, given a initial stack configuration, find such optimal set of movements to sort the list on the first stack?

Comment: Looks quite similar to towers of Hanoi except that the initial stack may not be sorted.

Comment: A*, probably. Similar problems (pancake sorting, four-peg Tower of Hanoi) have turned out to be very difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this simple question propably does not have any simple solution, I will not attempt to find a complete solution, but instead try to provide with you some points that may lead you to the right direction (or convince you to give up).

I see two different kind of approaches to this problem:

**Analytical method**

A theoreticians method would be to try to find a function that would calculate the complexity of any given position of the game. Optimally this would be the number of steps that is required to finish the game. If such complexity function is found, then it would be easy in each position to check the possible next moves, calculate the complexities of the positions after them and then choose the movement that produces least complex position.

Search for such a function should be started by setting the complexity of the completed game to 0. Then one should define symmetrical backward operations for the possible operations. The move-operation is symmetrical itself, so it can be used as is. But the join-operation must be replaced with unjoin, that cuts any stack anywhere in the middle and moves the ending of it into an empty stack. After that any position that can be reached by one move- or unjoin-operation will have the complexity of 1. Then any position that can be reached from those positions and does not already have lower complexity, will have complexity of 2. After repeating this for a few steps one should then try to search for patterns that would allow generating a function that could calculate the complexity of an arbitrary position.

This method might provide a very elegant and effective solution that could perhaps be quite easily proven to be optimal. But the obvious downside is that there is no guarantee that such a complexity function exists - at least in any practical form.

**A state machine**

A different approach that I at first thought to be more promising could be to define a set of rules on what plan the player should adopt in positions of certain characteristics. In this case the positions would be classified based on their characteristics and for a position in a given class a specific plan would be defined. Then the position classes would essentially be states in a state machine and the plans shifts between the states.

An example of a state and a plan for it would be a starting position, where number 1 (the lowest value) is somewhere in the middle of the stack. In this case a feasible plan could be to move all the numbers on 1 to to one of the empty stacks and when 1 is revealed, move it to the other empty stack to be the starting point for the final sorted stack.

The list of such states and their related plans would be a rather extesive, but perhaps doable. However, a bigger problem would be to prove that the plans in the states are optimal. For example the plan I gave for the starting position is surely logical, but there is no guarantee it is optimal.

The thought that made be sceptical about this approach was the following idea: Especially in games with a long starting stack, it may well be that the optimal sorting strategy is to divide the long stack in to the two other stacks with a specific division, then join the two or three stacks again to one long stack, divide again and repeat until the stack is sorted. In this case it would be very difficult to predict how the division to the two stacks should be made, since obvious plans may not work. For example it would be pointless to divide the numbers to stacks of smaller and larger numbers, since this partial sorting would be ruined on the next round. A better plan could be to create as many pairs of consecutive numbers as possible, but there's no saying this is optimal either.

In conclusion I think it is very possible that this problem has no other than brute force solutions, if the optimal result is searched. For sure there are methods for finding good results at least from general sorting science, but the absolute optimal is beyond them.